# NullPointerException on executing command on NavigationUI

Tags: android, navigation, uinavigationcontroller, android-architecture-components

Cant find what causes the problem with null exception. Making the project by the guide and it doesnt have this problem. using the same libraries versions like in guidr.

Error message

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.Navigation
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var navController: NavController
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        bottom_nav.setupWithNavController(navController)


        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp( navController, null)
    }
}
```

Comment: i know whart im talking about, cause i thought that spring autoinjected it in my code but i must to do it manualy with @Autowire and a variable.

Comment: Then your code obviously misses all the part of a [mcve]. Nothing in your question even remotely mentioned that.

Answer (score 14):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
```

you are missing `setSupportActionBar(toolbar)` between `setContentView` and `navController = ...`

Comment: The reason is: the navigation architecture components set the title of the `ActionBar` automatically with `setTitle()` whenever the `NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController` is used; so if there is no `supportActionBar`; then calling `setTitle()` will raise NPE

Comment: @Zain so how can we resolve it without set action bar?

Comment: @GuySadoun, Not sure what exactly your scenario is, but I guess right you'd omit using `NavigationUI.setupWithActionBar()` but that will make you manually treat everything on the ActionBar including its title

Answer (score 1):

res/values/styles under the app theme:

```
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

this seems to cause it. strange, because in guide it doesn't cause any trouble.